# Database of half-life for each drug

Tags: medical

Given a drug ingredient (e.g., as RxNorm ingredient code), is there a database that lists what is the half life of a drug. The database should have 1000+ ingredients. For example a small list is at wikipedia here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_half-life and the info is in drug infobox on wikipedia, but the user needs a comprehensive database.

Comment: The Wikipedia link you provided has a Wikidata entry on the left menu bar, so maybe Wikidata has more: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q686886

Comment: The link https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q686886 goes to the term for half life. It would have to be a wikidata property for a user to be able to fetch it that way.

Comment: if you want wikidata/Sparql support, you can edit or re-ask on this forum, or post on https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Request_a_query

Answer (score 1):

[OpenFDA](https://open.fda.gov/) has an [API](https://open.fda.gov/apis/) that has info about half-life under the key `pharmacokinetics`

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.brand_name:xanax&limit=1

but it seems to not be structured (so the numbers you are looking for come as part of the free text)

> "pharmacokinetics": [
>    "Pharmacokinetics Absorption Following oral administration, alprazolam is readily absorbed. Peak concentrations in
>   the plasma occur in 1 to 2 hours following administration. Plasma
>   levels are proportionate to the dose given; over the dose range of 0.5
>   to 3.0 mg, peak levels of 8.0 to 37 ng/mL were observed. Using a
>   specific assay methodology, the mean plasma elimination half-life of
>   alprazolam has been found to be about 11.2 hours (range: 6.3–26.9
>   hours) in healthy adults. Distribution In vitro, alprazolam is bound
>   (80 percent) to human serum protein. Serum albumin accounts for the
>   majority of the binding. Metabolism/Elimination Alprazolam is
>   extensively metabolized in humans, primarily by cytochrome P450 3A4
>   (CYP3A4), to two major metabolites in the plasma: 4-hydroxyalprazolam
>   and α-hydroxyalprazolam. A benzophenone derived from alprazolam is
>   also found in humans. Their half-lives appear to be similar to that of
>   alprazolam. The plasma concentrations of 4-hydroxyalprazolam and
>   α-hydroxyalprazolam relative to unchanged alprazolam concentration
>   were always less than 4%. The reported relative potencies in
>   benzodiazepine receptor binding experiments and in animal models of
>   induced seizure inhibition are 0.20 and 0.66, respectively, for
>   4-hydroxyalprazolam and α-hydroxyalprazolam. Such low concentrations
>   and the lesser potencies of 4-hydroxyalprazolam and
>   α-hydroxyalprazolam suggest that they are unlikely to contribute much
>   to the pharmacological effects of alprazolam. The benzophenone
>   metabolite is essentially inactive. Alprazolam and its metabolites are
>   excreted primarily in the urine. Special Populations Changes in the
>   absorption, distribution, metabolism and excretion of benzodiazepines
>   have been reported in a variety of disease states including
>   alcoholism, impaired hepatic function and impaired renal function.
>   Changes have also been demonstrated in geriatric patients. A mean
>   half-life of alprazolam of 16.3 hours has been observed in healthy
>   elderly subjects (range: 9.0–26.9 hours, n=16) compared to 11.0 hours
>   (range: 6.3–15.8 hours, n=16) in healthy adult subjects. In patients
>   with alcoholic liver disease the half-life of alprazolam ranged
>   between 5.8 and 65.3 hours (mean: 19.7 hours, n=17) as compared to
>   between 6.3 and 26.9 hours (mean=11.4 hours, n=17) in healthy
>   subjects. In an obese group of subjects the half-life of alprazolam
>   ranged between 9.9 and 40.4 hours (mean=21.8 hours, n=12) as compared
>   to between 6.3 and 15.8 hours (mean=10.6 hours, n=12) in healthy
>   subjects. Because of its similarity to other benzodiazepines, it is
>   assumed that alprazolam undergoes transplacental passage and that it
>   is excreted in human milk. Race Maximal concentrations and half-life
>   of alprazolam are approximately 15% and 25% higher in Asians compared
>   to Caucasians. Pediatrics The pharmacokinetics of alprazolam in
>   pediatric patients have not been studied. Gender Gender has no effect
>   on the pharmacokinetics of alprazolam. Cigarette Smoking Alprazolam
>   concentrations may be reduced by up to 50% in smokers compared to
>   non-smokers. Drug-Drug Interactions Alprazolam is primarily eliminated
>   by metabolism via cytochrome P450 3A (CYP3A). Most of the interactions
>   that have been documented with alprazolam are with drugs that inhibit
>   or induce CYP3A4. Compounds that are potent inhibitors of CYP3A would
>   be expected to increase plasma alprazolam concentrations. Drug
>   products that have been studied in vivo, along with their effect on
>   increasing alprazolam AUC, are as follows: ketoconazole, 3.98 fold;
>   itraconazole, 2.70 fold; nefazodone, 1.98 fold; fluvoxamine, 1.96
>   fold; and erythromycin, 1.61 fold (see CONTRAINDICATIONS, WARNINGS,
>   and PRECAUTIONS–Drug Interactions). CYP3A inducers would be expected
>   to decrease alprazolam concentrations and this has been observed in
>   vivo. The oral clearance of alprazolam (given in a 0.8 mg single dose)
>   was increased from 0.90±0.21 mL/min/kg to 2.13±0.54 mL/min/kg and the
>   elimination t1/2 was shortened (from 17.1±4.9 to 7.7 ±1.7 h) following
>   administration of 300 mg/day carbamazepine for 10 days (see
>   PRECAUTIONS–Drug Interactions). However, the carbamazepine dose used
>   in this study was fairly low compared to the recommended doses
>   (1000–1200 mg/day); the effect at usual carbamazepine doses is
>   unknown. Interactions involving HIV protease inhibitors (eg,
>   ritonavir) and alprazolam are complex and time dependent. Short-term
>   low doses of ritonavir (4 doses of 200 mg) reduced alprazolam
>   clearance to 41% of control values, prolonged its elimination
>   half-life (mean values, 30 versus 13 h) and enhanced clinical effects.
>   However, upon extended exposure to ritonavir (500 mg, twice daily),
>   CYP3A induction offset this inhibition. Alprazolam AUC and Cmax was
>   reduced by 12% and 16%, respectively, in the presence of ritonavir
>   (see WARNINGS). The ability of alprazolam to induce human hepatic
>   enzyme systems has not yet been determined. However, this is not a
>   property of benzodiazepines in general. Further, alprazolam did not
>   affect the prothrombin or plasma warfarin levels in male volunteers
>   administered sodium warfarin orally."
>             ],

---

you can scroll through this forum with the tag [openfda](/questions/tagged/openfda) to see how other users are using it. For example, using an API endpoint to get a list of  drug_ingredient/brand_names and then the above endpoint with LIMIT > $max for those in the list.